# RDD from label Array and data Array in python/spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two python arrays of the same length. They are generated from reading two separate text files. One represents labels; let it be called "labelArray". The other is an array of data arrays; let it be called "dataArray". I want to turn them into an RDD object of LabeledPoint. How can I do this?

Comment: Show us the first few rows of each data array. Then we can help write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the source dataArray and lableArray are lists as described in the code. You can try something like below to create an merged RDD

```
>>> lableArray=['l1','l2','l3']
>>> dataArray=['d1','d2','d3']
>>> rdd2=sc.parallelize(lableArray)
>>> rdd1=sc.parallelize(dataArray)
>>> rdd1.collect()
['d1', 'd2', 'd3']
>>> rdd2.collect()
['l1', 'l2', 'l3']
>>> rdd=rdd2.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x:(x[1],x[0])).join(rdd1.zipWithIndex().map(lambda y:(y[1],y[0]))).map(lambda x:x[1])
>>> rdd.collect()
[('l1', 'd1'), ('l2', 'd2'), ('l3', 'd3')]
```

Here "rdd' is the final result created by combining both the dataArray and lableArray

Answer (score 1):

Spark have a function takeSample  which can merge two RDD in to an RDD.